# Is it possible to redirect at home page if session is live using Spring-Security?

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security, redirect

I am using Spring Security for Web application development. I do not want to allow users to do registration while they are already loggedIn in the System.

So suppose, there is url for registration is `/registration` and for home page is `/home`. 
Now I want to redirect at `/home` if user tries to hit `/registration` while session is live. Is it possible using `spring-security` ? I can check session in controller method and redirect manually...that I know. but is there any config with spring-security? Thanks.

Comment: Configure anonymous access and allow only access to the Registration part of your website for anonymous users. If an authenticated user tries it he will get a access denied page. It isn't a redirect but that is what you can do in spring security.

Comment: Hi Thanks @M.Deinum, Its not exactly what I want..but the information you shared is really helpful. Appreciate :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with Spring Security only. Add a new security:http element before your existing one as follows:

```
 <security:http pattern="/registration" access-denied-page="/home" entry-point-ref="forbiddenEntryPoint">
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/registration" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
 </security:http>

 <bean id="forbiddenEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>
```

The entry point implementation doesn't really matter, because it won't be invoked. It's just mandatory to define it.

System will now monitor URL `/registration` and when it's hit by a user without `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` (= an authenticated user) it will serve content from `/home` instead.